Can't delete from many-to-many relationship
I have what appears to be a textbook example of an indirect many-to-many relationship.
I can retrieve and add new entities to the relationship but cannot remove them.
From all the examples I've followed it just doesn't work.
Data models:
public class Job
{
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string Name  { get; set; }

    public virtual Account PrimaryAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AccountAlert>? AccountAlerts { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string Name  { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AccountAlert>? AccountAlerts { get; set; }
}

public class AccountAlert
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
}

DbContext:
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AccountAlert> AccountAlerts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().ToTable("account");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Job>().ToTable("job");
        modelBuilder.Entity<AccountAlert>().ToTable("account_alert").HasKey(x => new { x.JobId, x.AccountId });
    }
}

Remove code:
var job = _dataContext.Set<Job>()
                      .Where(x => x.JobId == jobId)
                      .Include("AccountAlerts")
                      .Include("AccountAlerts.Account")
                      .AsNotTracked()
                      .Single();

foreach(var alert in job.AccountAlerts)
{
    // Doesn't work
    job.AccountAlerts.Remove(alert);
    
    // Doesn't work
    job.AccountAlerts.Remove(new AccountAlert { JobId = alert.JobId, AccountId = alert.AccountId });
    
    // Doesn't work
    job.AccountAlerts.Remove(new AccountAlert { AccountId = alert.AccountId });
}

await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();


Another solution to the problem besides the one suggested by Steve Py(which should work) is to delete directly from the mapping table:
// you can take accountAlerts by AccountId or JobId
var accountAlerts = await _dataContext.AccountAlerts
                   .Where(x => accountIds.Contains(x.AccountId))
                   .ToListAsync();

context2.RemoveRange(accountAlerts);
await context2.SaveChangesAsync();

Or if you want to clear all alerts in the job just use Clear()
var job = await _dataContext.Set<Job>()
                  .Where(x => x.JobId == jobId)
                  .Include(x => x.AccountAlerts)
                  .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

if (job is not null)
{
    job.AccountAlerts.Clear();
    await context2.SaveChangesAsync();
}


var job = _dataContext.Set<Job>()
                  .Where(x => x.JobId == jobId)
                  .Include("AccountAlerts")
                  .Include("AccountAlerts.Account")
                  .AsNotTracked()
                  .Single();

If in the above example you mean you are using .AsNoTracking() then No, you cannot remove items from the returned Job and call SaveChanges, that relies on Change Tracking. Use:
var job = await _dataContext.Set<Job>()
                  .Where(x => x.JobId == jobId)
                  .Include(x => x.AccountAlerts)
                  .SingleAsync();

then
foreach(var alert in job.AccountAlerts)
{
    job.AccountAlerts.Remove(alert);
}

await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();

... will work.

Does adding _dataContext.Set<Job>().Update(job); fix this by adding it to the tracker before calling SaveChanges?

Not likely since the collection of account alerts would not be associated with the now-tracked job.  You could attach each and every account alert  associated with the job then remove it. This would only be advisable if you are loading the job and account alerts elsewhere as detached entities and passing them into a method to persist changes.
